# 'module' object has no attribute 'now' will trying to create a CSV

Tags: python, django, csv, django-views

Hello I'm having problems importing to csv, I get that error, the problem is that I have the same code running in other machine and it runs perfectly. 
What am I missing do I need to install an other library for this?.

```
def exportar_a_csv_grl(request):
    #Fecha actual
    hoy = datetime.now().date()
    #Creado el:
    creado_hoy = hoy.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="Reporte de Miembros ' +      creado_hoy + '.csv"'
response['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv; charset=utf-8'
response.write("\xEF\xBB\xBF")

writer = csv.writer(response)
miembros = Miembro.objects.all().extra(select={'miem_monto': "aplicacionmediexcel_miembro_monto.monto"},
                                       tables=["aplicacionmediexcel_miembro_monto"], where=[
        """aplicacionmediexcel_miembro.id=aplicacionmediexcel_miembro_monto.miembro_id"""])
#.extra(select = {'precio':'''select aplicacionmediexcel_miembro_monto.monto from aplicacionmediexcel_miembro_monto, aplicacionmediexcel_miembro where  aplicacionmediexcel_miembro.id = aplicacionmediexcel_miembro_monto.miembro_id'''})
miembros_colec = Miembro_colec.objects.all().extra(
    select={'miem_monto': "aplicacionmediexcel_colectivo_miembro_monto.monto"},
    tables=["aplicacionmediexcel_colectivo_miembro_monto"],
    where=["""aplicacionmediexcel_miembro_colec.id=aplicacionmediexcel_colectivo_miembro_monto.miembro_colec_id"""])
dependientes = Dependiente.objects.all()
dependientes_colec = Dependiente_colec.objects.all()
writer.writerow(['Creado el:             ' + creado_hoy + ' '])
writer.writerow([''])
#csv_data = (
#   ('ID Miembro', 'Apellido Paterno', 'Nombre', 'MI', 'Numero de Seguro Social', 'Tipo de contratacion','Tier', 'Tipo de dependiente', 'Fecha de nacimiento', 'Edad', 'Sexo', 'Estado Civil', 'Correo Electronico', 'Domicilio', 'Ciudad','Estado', 'Codigo Postal', 'Telefono', 'Idioma', 'Region de servicio', 'Medico', 'Fecha Efectiva', 'Tipo Plan', 'Grupo', 'Monto'),
#)
writer.writerow(
    ['ID Miembro', 'Apellido Paterno', 'Nombre', 'MI', 'Número de Seguro Social', 'Tipo de contratación',
     'Tier', 'Tipo de dependiente', 'Fecha de nacimiento', 'Edad', 'Sexo', 'Estado Civil', 'Correo Electrónico',
     'Domicilio', 'Ciudad',
     'Estado', 'Código Postal', 'Teléfono', 'Idioma', 'Región de servicio', 'Médico', 'Actividad', 'Fecha Efectiva',
     'Fecha Renovación', 'Tipo Plan', 'Grupo', 'Monto'])

#t = loader.get_template('my_template_name.txt')
#c = Context({
#   'miembros': miembros,
#})
#response.write(t.render(c))
```

Comment: try `from datetime import datetime` instead of `import datetime`

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You probably have

```
import datetime
```

change that to

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 7, 13, 57, 18, 456504)
>>>
```

Also, you will run into issues due to indentation. Please fix those.

Comment: +1.  Or don't change the import and do `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: I fix that problem with the first answer  but now i'm getting, UnicodeEncodeError at /brokers/csv/ 
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: [Check these](https://www.google.com/search?q=UnicodeEncodeError+at+%2Fbrokers%2Fcsv%2F+'ascii'+codec+can't+encode+character&oq=UnicodeEncodeError+at+%2Fbrokers%2Fcsv%2F+'ascii'+codec+can't+encode+character&aqs=chrome.0.69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: So here's a question: what if you already have it set as `from datetime import datetime` and using it as `datetime.now()`, but are still getting that error???

Comment: Normally, what i do is: `from datetime import datetime as dtdatetime` so that way things are more explicit @streetlogics

Comment: Thanks @karthikr - it's funny you say that too, because that's exactly what I ended up doing essentially (mine was called `from datetime import datetime as datetime_admin`).  I was considering doing some sort of try/except block to reimport it after the other import statements, but just realized I'd be taking the problem from peter caused by sally and making peter being the one handing the error back to sally (aka whichever imported item was expecting it to be imported as simply `import datetime`).

Answer (score 12):

When you do

```
import datetime
```

you have to use

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 14, 1, 15, 58, 606802)
```

otherwise if you import like

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 14, 1, 17, 31, 772406)
```

But on some machine you could refer to wrong datetime module because of sys.path , instead of doing `from datetime import datetime` or `import datetime` make a habbit of using

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem when i used

```
from datetime import datetime,date,timedelta
import pytz
utc=pytz.UTC
today = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

Solution for this which i will suggest is to import all the dependencies

```
from datetime import *
import pytz
utc=pytz.UTC
today = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=utc)
```