# Python datetime module problems

Tags: python-3.x, linux, datetime, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm using the `datetime` module in python3.7.
When I run it from terminal it throws an error:

```
File "/home/user/Desktop/Yazılım/datetime.py", line 2, in <module>
x=datetime.datetime.now()
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'
```

Comment: Did you import datetime module? Works in mine ( py -3.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you named your file datetime.py
it may lead to confusion when calling it from outside.

you should rename it to something else like my_datetime.py

you also need to import datetime before using it

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change

```
import datetime
```

with

```
from datetime import datetime
```

credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19231474/12770606